# Show progress dialog attached over to textview

Tags: android, layout, textview, loader, progressdialog

I need to show Progress circle attached over to the TextView but it should be in such way that it wont resist the user to tap on other screen components. something like this

[image]

Any clue?

Comment: What you are looking for is progressbar and not progressdialog.

Comment: absolutely but instead of it appear over to screen and block other components, I want it merely on a textview.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrap the textview and a Progress bar widget in an appropriate layout. More on ProgressBar here:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html

Answer (score 2):

[image] set Outer Layout as Framelayout, inside TextView/EditText and ProgressBar set `(layout gravity "Right")`

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingRight="24dp"
        android:text="Getting Location"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textSize="12dp" >

        <requestFocus />
    </TextView>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/ProgressBar01"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp" />
</FrameLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/EditText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingRight="24dp"
        android:text="http://example.com"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textSize="12dp" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have done something like this but it includes an icon as well. Here’s a ready baked code for those who are looking for this.

In your layout use

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/my_element"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_height="20dp">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_place"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text=""/>

    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Small"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

This is a linearlayout which contains the textview (an additional icon in front just for kicks) and a small-sized spinning progressbar.

In the activity/fragment add

```
LinearLayout llMyElement;
```

On the corresponding onCreate/onCreateView use

```
llMyElement = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.my_element);
```

On the AsyncTask’s onPostExecute or wherever you want to set the text after a process call `setLoadingText(llMyElement, “Some Result");`

And include this helper function that sets the text into your Activity class or anywhere suitable such as a Util class.

```
public void setLoadingText(LinearLayout layout, String text)
{
    int count = layout.getChildCount();
    for(int  i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        if(layout.getChildAt(i) instanceof TextView)
            ((TextView) layout.getChildAt(i)).setText(text);
        if(layout.getChildAt(i) instanceof ProgressBar)
            layout.getChildAt(i).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
```

And that’s it.. Enjoy!!

Answer (score 1):

Put them inside a `FrameLayout`:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_weight="1">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/my_info_card"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>
    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Small"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

This way the `ProgressBar` appears over the `TextView`. Surely you can hide the ProgressBar whenever you want by `setVisibility()`. You can also set each layout's gravity by `android:layout_gravity`. In the example above it looks like this:

[image: ProgressBar over TextView]

Answer (score 0):

Such a thing is not possible with just a TextView IMO. I guess the best way to mimick such an effect would be to have a LinearLayout with Textview and an Imageview (horizontal orientation). Have the imageview invisible initially. Toggle the visibility of the imageview conditionally. That is, when the action starts, set the visibility and when the action is over,hide it back again.Hope you get the idea.