# Set gravity of a layout

Tags: android-layout, android

I'm trying to set right gravity to a linear layout in the OnPreExecute method,
but the dialog still shows my hebrew text in the left side.
What is the problem with my code ?

```
private ProgressDialog dialog;
    private Context context;
    private LinearLayout layout;

    public MyTask(Activity activity) {
        context = activity;
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        layout = new LinearLayout(context);
    }

    protected void onPreExecute() {           
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(-1, -2);             
        layout.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
        TextView loadMsg = new TextView(context);
        loadMsg.setText("טוען...");
        loadMsg.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
        layout.addView(loadMsg, params);
        dialog.setView(layout);         
    //  dialog.setContentView(R.layout.loaddialog);
    //   dialog.show();
    }
```

Comment: Take a look - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6748118/show-progress-dialog-attached-over-to-textview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried to fix your problem try to use it. It is working for me.

```
    LinearLayout lp = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
    lp.setMinimumWidth(100);
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    lp.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
    TextView loadMsg = new TextView(this);
    loadMsg.setText("my msg");
    loadMsg.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    loadMsg.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
    lp.addView(loadMsg, params);
    Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
    dialog.setContentView(lp);
    dialog.show();
```